# How to call a function from several classes extending the same class

Tags: java, oop

I'm having some trouble with structure.

I have several objects of classes which extend an Entity class, some of these classes overwrite a function A() from the Entity class, requiring a certain input (ex. A(int input)).

Is there any way i can call the function A() of all the objects at the same time(meaning, not having seperate lists for every class)?

I'm now using an arrayList(entities) to store all the objects and typecast them in a for-loop. This seems rather messy and im pretty sure i'm misunderstanding some basic principles of OOP.

```
    for (int i=0;i<entities.size();i++) {           
        Entity entityPre = (Entity) entities.get(i);

        if (entityPre instanceof subClass) { 
            subClass entity= (subClass) entityPre;
            entity.A(int Input);
        }else{
            entityPre.A();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: All subclasses of your Entity class should share the same method signature if possible. How about passing that input to the method no matter what type it is and simply ignore it in some of the implementations of function `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really overriding `A()` as you changed the method arguments hence changing the method signature.

Therefore, you cannot use the 'regular' overriding mechanisms and you are stuck with your current implementation.

If you add the method argument to your base class (even though it is not using it), you can override the method properly and simplify your loop content. But personally, I would only perform this modification is the additional argument makes *any* sense to the base class!

Answer (score 0):

If `A(int)` is a method of the base Entity class, overridden in subclasses, then you don't need any type cast. That's what polymorphism is all about:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {           
    entity.A(input);
}
```

Side note: you should really choose better names for your methods and variables, and respect Java naming conventions: methods start with a lower-case letter, whereas classes start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: My problem is that i would like to use variable input depending on the subclass that extends the Entity class. I might be trying something that's just not possible though

Comment: Then assume that every entity might need the input, and only have one `A(int input)` method. If the subclass doesn't care about the input, it just needs to ignore it.

Comment: What if each subclass uses a different input?

Comment: Ask each Entity instance which input it needs, and pass it the right one. Or pass an object containing every possible input, and let the Entity instance get the one it needs from the object.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand that. How would i ask an Entity instance which input it needs?

Comment: By having a method in Entity, that each subclass could override, called `getKindOfInputForA()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is correct.

> Is there any way i can call the function A() of all the objects at the same time

No, a method can be called using **a** object only, unless it is declared as `static.`

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what u want actually, and in above description what is "A" it is a function or class if it is a function then how can u write like this 'if (entityPre instanceof A) { 
            A entity= (A) entityPre;
            entity.doLogic(int Input);
        }' first u have to read about "instanceOf" method the answer of JB will help u.

Comment: Sorry about that, i noticed my mistake and edited it, you must have seen it before i changed it.

Comment: if your input is of specific type the try variable argument and you want to call method from main class u have loop in through switch case